# Adding and accessing a searchView in the actionbar

Tags: android

This is my first question in Stack Overflow, so please don't mind if I there are any mistakes...
I want to add a SearchView to an activity's Actionbar, so that when the user types a name in the SearchView, the RecyclerView would be filtered to give the relevant names.
This is the code that I have for the activity's onCreateOptionsMenu method:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);

    searchViewInstructors = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.searchViewInstructors).getActionView();

    searchViewInstructors.setActivated(true);
    searchViewInstructors.setQueryHint("Search by name");
    searchViewInstructors.onActionViewExpanded();
    searchViewInstructors.setIconified(true);
    searchViewInstructors.clearFocus();
    searchViewInstructors.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

And this is the code for res/menu/search.xml, where the SearchView is an item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".TrainersActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/searchViewInstructors"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="Search by name"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

The problem I'm facing, and the reason I've asked the question even with the many answers I found on Stack Overflow for the exact same or similar questions, is that no matter what I did, I get a nullPointerException:

```
12-05 18:58:33.559 19381-19381/worldontheotherside.wordpress.com.drvingapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                         Process: worldontheotherside.wordpress.com.drvingapp, PID: 19381
                                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setActivated(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                                             at worldontheotherside.wordpress.com.drvingapp.TrainersActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(TrainersActivity.java:78)
                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3307)
                                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:320)
                                                                                             at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:95)
                                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:333)
                                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1372)
                                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1652)
                                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:137)
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

I appreciate it if someone would tell me exactly what I'm doing wrong, and how to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
```

instead of

```
android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
```